# Failed to load ApplicationContext when running all unit tests together

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, unit-testing, mockito

I have a lot of unit tests which work perfectly when I run them individually.
The problem comes when I run them all together with mvn Test. When I do that I get this error in some of the tests, not all of them so I don't understand why this is happening.

The exception I get is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

Comment: You are using too many differen variations of the configuration, leading to multiple application contexts being loaded, and thus multiple datasources. Eventually leading to too many connections to your postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last (root) cause:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining 
connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser 
connections
```

Go to /opt/lce/db/postgresql or wherever your configuration is and edit the postgresql.conf file. Look for max_connections parameter (should be 40 as default). Increase it to 50, reboot the server and try to run list-client again. [Source](https://community.tenable.com/s/question/0D53a00008O6ZR4CAN/psql-error-remaining-connection-slots-are-reserved-for-nonreplicated-superuser-connections)

Please do not set max_connections too high, as it'll consume resources!

Edit: another thing that comes to mind: Check all your tests, if they really close the used database connections after each test.

```java
  Connection c = // however you get your Connection...
  //... your test code
  @AfterEach
  public void closeDatabaseConnection(){
    c.close();
  }
```

Or refactor your tests so that they all use only one DB-Connection (e.g. by defining a superclass for all your tests that handles the DB-Connection)

For unit tests you normally do not want to use a real database connection at all, but you want to mock the database.
Even if you don't want, or can not mock the database, then you might want to use a fast in-memory database just for the unit-tests instead of using a full blown PostgreSQL. Try `h2` or `derby` for that matter in your tests.

More information on how to configure `h2` for spring-(boot) can be found here: [spring-testing-separate-data-source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source)